# XLRDError: Expected BOF record; found 0x4b50

Tags: python, excel

I don't think there is something wrong with the codes. Can you help me? I need help.        Thank you!

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

wb = open_workbook('/pdf-ex/exc.xlsx','rb')
for s in wb.sheets():
    print 'Sheet:',s.name
    for row in range(s.nrows):
        values=[]
        for col in range(s.ncols):
            values.append(s.cell(row,col).value)
        print ",".join(values)
    print
```

Comment: This thread indicates that you have a `xlsm` file: http://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/2e6f1d2713078493

Comment: I also had same problem. solved by saving the xlsx file as xls file.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and resolved it by upgrading to version 0.8.0.

Prior to that version, xlsx/xlsm were not supported.

Release announcement: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-August/627757.html

Latest version: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd/